# Seperating a string by finding the postal code in the string

Tags: javascript, string, split

So i have afield that can come in these kinds for example

```
Bakersfieldroad 1 344 75 Newcastle
South Matesroad 345 356 72 Essex
Muckley-buckleyroad 23 435 72 London
```

Here i would want to put a `,` between the address and the postal code so somehow i need to figure out when the postal code starts. Is there any good way to do this since addresses can vary a lot. so i guess focusing on the postal code as it will always be 3 numbers followed by a space and then 2 numbers

Comment: I would probably iterate over the string and keep track of the whitespaces which would then tell you when you found a 3 number substring, white space, then a 2 number string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression to capture the postcode, and replace it with itself surrounded in quotes like so:

```js
const str = `Bakersfieldroad 1 344 75 Newcastle
South Matesroad 345 356 72 Essex
Muckley-buckleyroad 23 435 72 London`;

const res = str.replace(/\s(\d{3}\s\d{2})\s/g, ", $1, ");
console.log(res);
```

The regular expression above will match a whitespace character (ie: a space) `\s`, and then group the next three digits, a space, and next two digits (ie the postcode) in a capture group `(\d{3}\s\d{2})`, it will then also match a space after the postcode using `\s`. You can then reference the capture group in the replacement argument using `$1`.